# Не срабатывает кнопка в боте

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Создал файл main, в котором прописал основные команд, затем создал второй файлик и в нем пытаюсь создать второй набор команд конкретного направления работы бота и чего то не могу понять, что не так. Импортировал из мэйна диспатчер и бота

```
from main import dp, bots
```

А теперь пытаюсь сделать кнопку, но функция не срабатывает

```
 @dp.message(text=['Дневник стажировки'])
async def bar_dnevnik(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Дневник стажировки', reply_markup=kb.bar_dnevnik)
    await state.set_state(BarmenState.bar_main)
```

Что забыл?

Сразу предупрежу, так как aiogram третий, то тут пишется именно та, без _handler

```
INFO:aiogram.event:Update id=5947724 is not handled. Duration 1 ms by bot id=5237273197
```

Comment: А зачем вам сырой 3 айограм? Думаю лучше вернутся на 2-ку

Comment: @oleksandrigo Да начал изучение с него не зная что он слишком новый, а сейчас, когда написано уже очень много как то обидно переписывать и изучать заново вторую версию

Comment: Ну я сомневаюсь что вам кто-то сможет помочь с 3-ей версией

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как нельзя импортировать из мейна димпетчер и бота, надо использовать роутер
в файле с обработчиком кнопок импортируете

```
from aiogram import Router
from aiogram.types import Message, CallbackQuery
```

далее инициализируем роутер

```
router: Router = Router()
```

далее ваш код

```
@router.message(text=['Дневник стажировки'])
async def bar_dnevnik(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('Дневник стажировки', reply_markup=kb.bar_dnevnik)
    await state.set_state(BarmenState.bar_main)
```

А в файле мэйн надо не забыть импортировать файл с обработчиками например он называется у вас user_andlers и затем зарегистрировать роутер в диспетчере
Например:

```
dp.include_router(user_handlers.router)
```